# How to remove nan from pandas series index?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan])
df.pop(np.nan)

Type error : can not do label indexing on class pandas.core.indexes.base.Index with these index [nan] of class float
```

I tried doing

```
df.reset_index().dropna().set_index('index')
```

But then when I do `df.pop('a')` it gives me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `s` is a pandas Series, then `s.reset_index()` returns a DataFrame with the index of the Series as one of its columns (named `index` by default). Note that `s.reset_index(drop=True)` returns a Series, but discards the index.

One solution to your task is to select the one and only column named `0` from the DataFrame built by your last line:

```
# setup with the name "s" to represent a Series (keep "df" for DataFrames)
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a','b','c',np.nan]) 
res1 = s.reset_index().dropna().set_index('index')[0]
res1
index
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Another option is to drop null index labels by reindexing the Series:

```
res2 = s.loc[s.index.dropna()]
res2
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```